# Combinatorics circular sitting problem

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are $3$ americans, $2$ britishers, $1$ portugese, $1$ chinese and they are allowed to sit around a circular table so that no two people of same nationality sit side by side. Answer is $3148$. I ve tried it many a times but...answer given in book is 3148

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, you should show what you have attempted so that users can detect any errors you may have made.  Explaining what you know and where you are stuck is also helpful.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

The Americans must be placed:  A _ _ A _ A _

There are $3!$ ways to do that.

There are four remaining people to put in the four seats.  This can be done in $4!$ ways, two of which have the British in the two adjacent slots; these cases must be eliminated.

Hence $4! - 2 = 22$ cases where we do not care where the first person is seated (i.e., we can rotate the table).  If we do care about orientation, we multiply by 6.

Answer:  $3! (4!-2) 6/2 = 396$.

Comment: Ooopsss... yes... another factor of 2.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, that was not what I meant.  What I was trying to say is that once you seat the Americans, there are $4$ bad cases to be eliminated from the $4!$ ways you can seat the other four people since for each of the two ways the British could be seated together, there are two ways to seat the Portugese and Chinese people in the remaining two positions.